# Dynamic binding inside constructor for virtual Function in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual-functions

As per the standard, we know that constructor always go for an early binding of a virtual function inside them because they don't have complete idea the derived class hierarchy downside.

In this case if early binding is used inside my base constructor, I have passed a derived object to a base class pointer which is completely acceptable (an upcasting is done here). If early binding is used the selection of the virtual function should be based on the type of the pointer (which is Base * here) but not the content of the pointer(the object pointed by the pointer because we don't know the exact object being pointed). In that case since the pointer type is Base * we should have invoked only Base class virtual function in both cases. Could some one please clarify this?

I think dynamic binding is used here rather than early binding. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

The first line of the output which invokes base is completely fine

```
class Base
    {
        public:
        Base(){
            fun();
        }
        Base(Base *p)
        {
            p->fun();
        }
        virtual void fun()
        {
            cout<<"In Base"<<endl;
        }
    };

    class Derived : public Base
    {
        public:
        void fun()
        {
            cout<<"In Derived"<<endl;
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        Derived d;
        Base b(&d);
    }
```

O/P :

```
In Base
In Derived
```

Comment: "we know that constructor always go for an early binding" wrong

Answer (score 1):

The rule for virtual calls within a constructor body applies to an object *currently being constructed*, because that object is not yet considered to be an object of any derived class. (And there's a similar rule for an object currently being destroyed.) It has little to do with "early binding" in the sense of using a compile-time type, such as the syntax `ClassName::member_func()` forces.

Your code has two different objects `d` and `b`, and the constructor of `d` has entirely finished by the time you get to the `p->fun();` line.

In detail:

1. The program enters `main`.
2. The object `d` is created using the implicitly declared default constructor of `Derived`.
3. The first thing `Derived::Derived()` does is create the base class subobject, by calling the default constructor `Base::Base()`.
4. The body of `Base::Base()` calls `fun()`.  Since we have not yet entered the body of the `Derived::Derived()` constructor, this virtual lookup invokes `Base::fun()`.
5. `Base::Base()` finishes.
6. The body of `Derived::Derived()`, which is empty, executes and finishes.
7. Back in `main`, the object `b` is created by passing a pointer to `d` to the constructor `Base::Base(Base*)`.
8. The body of `Base::Base(Base *p)` calls `p->fun()`. Since `p` is a pointer to `d`, which is already a completely constructed object of type `Derived`, this virtual lookup invokes `Derived::fun()`.

Contrast with this slightly different example, where we define a default constructor of `Derived` to pass `this` (implicitly converted to `Base*`) to the constructor for the `Base` subobject.  (This is valid, though could be risky if the pointer were used in other ways, such as in an initializer for a base or member of `Base`.)

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Base
{
public:
    Base(){
        fun();
    }
    Base(Base *p)
    {
        p->fun();
    }
    virtual void fun()
    {
        cout<<"In Base"<<endl;
    }
};

class Derived
{
public:
    Derived() : Base(this) {}
    virtual void fun() override
    {
        cout << "In Derived" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
}
```

This program will print just "In Base", since now in `Base::Base(Base *p)`, `p` does point at the same object which is currently being constructed.

Comment: @aschelper, very nice explanation. As per your last statement "this" which is sent to base class constructor has the value of derived object or base object?

Comment: @user2906818 neither, a pointer is a distinct value to the thing it points to. At that point it is an invalid pointer-to-derived that is implicitly convertible to a valid pointer-to-base. In the body of the constructor it is a valid pointer-to-derived

Comment: "_The "early binding" rule you describe applies to an object currently being constructed_" What do you mean by "early binding"?

Comment: @curiousguy That's how the OP described it, though I've never heard the term before.

Comment: @aschepler Early binding means that the function called is selected by on the types of the expressions used, at compile time ("early"); as the OP puts it: "_If early binding is used the selection of the virtual function should be based on the type of the pointer (which is Base * here) but not the content of the pointer_"

Comment: @curiousguy I see, thanks. Edited the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that C++ classes are constructed from Base classes to derived classes and virtual call table of the complete object is created when the object creation process is completed. Therefore, the base class function is called in the code excerpt above. Unless otherwise mandatory, you should never make virtual function calls in the constructor. Below is an excerpt from [Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ Style and Technique FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html):

- In a constructor, the virtual call mechanism is disabled because 
  overriding from derived classes hasn’t yet happened. Objects are constructed from the base up, “base before derived”.
- Destruction is done “derived class before base class”, so virtual 
  functions behave as in constructors: Only the local definitions are used – 
  and no calls are made to overriding functions to avoid touching the (now 
  destroyed) derived class part of the object.

Comment: Very Nice explanantion. So you mean when we are constructing the derived object for the first time we enter in to the default Base constructor and since the derived object is not yet constructed by that time we go for an early binding and call the Base Virtual function. IN the second case since we have the derived object which is already formed we go for a dynamic binding here and hence call Derived virtual function. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: @user2906818 "_we go for an early binding_" no, we go for a virtual call based on the real type of the object, as always

Comment: "_the virtual call mechanism is disabled_" no

Comment: @curiousguy Did you check [Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ Style and Technique FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html)?

Comment: @CanYuce Why would I need to read that resource? Either way, I'm right and those who disagree with me are wrong.

Comment: @curiousguy because you claim that the virtual call mechanism is not disabled until the object is built up. Can you please further clarify it?

Comment: @CanYuce A call of a virtual function (using an unqualified name obviously) is always virtual: the function that ends up being called is determined NOT by the type of the expression (also called static type) but the type of object on which it is called (also called dynamic type). (This is sometimes called "late binding" semantic.) Being "inside" a constructor doesn't change the semantic of C++ expression. Also, what do you call the "inside" of a constructor? The scope (syntaxic inside) or the time when a constructor is running (dynamic inside)?

Comment: I'm sorry you had to read that **grossly misleading** claim "_the virtual call mechanism is disabled because overriding from derived classes hasn't yet happened_": 1) "virtual call mechanism is disabled" is plain wrong; virtual calls are always virtual, based on dynamic type (late binding) 2) "_overriding from derived classes hasn't yet happened_" is CORRECT: there is no overrider and you end up calling the base class definition of the virtual function `foo()` during the execution of the constructor of the base class on `foo()` or `this->foo()`, or `auto &x=*this; x.foo();`...

Comment: In the base class constructor `Base::Base()`, by definition the object being constructed is a `Base`, each virtual function has itself as final overrider, so all virtual calls of the form `this->f()` ends up calling the function that would be called by `this->Base::f()`, **so you can have early binding**, which is still has late binding semantic as specified. In general when the final overrider is known, the implementation can do early binding and guarantee "late" binding (based on dynamic type).

Comment: When a virtual call is made on an lvalue that doesn't clearly designate the currently constructed object, the compiler must still do regular late binding (use the vptr). Either way, the programmer should only be concerned by the concept of final overrider: the declaration of the overrider in the most derived loose base class (incl. the derived class itself) of the type of the object that overrides all other overriders and which is called. During construction, the existence of subobjects starts before the objects in which they will live; the type of `*this` changes accordingly.